# Wait until onCreate is finished

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I start a Service from a BroadcastReceiver like this

```
Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(service);

String s = "Hello World";
MyService.addString(s);
```

addString is a static function which add the String to a ListView. Now I have the problem that this function is called while MyService onCreate() is running and the ListView is not initialized. What can I do to wait until the onCreate method is finished?

Comment: On behalf of @fedepaol and myself, could you clarify the sequence here. Neither a BroadcastReceiver nor a Service would normally initiatise a ListView (unless, I guess, you are doing something with AppWidgets). A little more context would really help give good answers - thanks.

Comment: The Service has a WindowManager which creates an overalay view with a ListView on it and there I want to add new items.

Comment: Thank you - in which case I would think that @fedepaol has the easiest option for you: pass all the information you need from the broadcast receiver to the service in the Intent you use to start the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a guide describing `Activity` lifecycle in Android http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

The `onStart` method is called soon after the `onCreate` is finished.

In other words start your service from `onStart` method of the activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // start service
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnStart()` called after `onCreate()` for more details follow [LifeCycle of service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)

Comment: care to explain a bit more?

Comment: `Service.onStart` has been deprecated in Android 2.0 and won't be called in Android 2.1+

Comment: @vmironov `onStartCommand` will work earlier i thought you are using activity